# Start touch movement from child view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a subview inside my superview. Inside the subview I have another subview called circle.

This circle is a draggable circle. I can drag the circle by touching the circle and moving. The problem is, If I touch anywhere else on the subview and move, the circle moves. How do I prevent this from happening.

The following code is placed inside subview's class and used for moving the circle.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    startPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:circle];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches){

        CGPoint newPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        newPoint.x -= startPoint.x;
        newPoint.y -= startPoint.y;
        CGRect frm = [circle frame];
        frm.origin = newPoint;
        [circle setFrame:frm];

    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand there are three view SuperView-->SubView1-->Subview(circle). I assume the code is writer in subView1. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Code is in Subview 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try ignoring touch which is not there in your Circle View?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
                UITouch *touch1 = [touches anyObject];
                if(touch1.view == circle)
                {
                    startPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
                }
                else
                {
                    startPoint = nil;
                }
            }

            - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

                if (!startPoint) //If touch didnt start on circle view then ignore it
                {
                    return;
                }
                for (UITouch *touch in touches){

                    CGPoint newPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
                    newPoint.x -= startPoint.x;
                    newPoint.y -= startPoint.y;
                    CGRect frm = [circle frame];
                    frm.origin = newPoint;
                    [circle setFrame:frm];

                }
            }
```